# Editing the styles of all parent elements using javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I'm attempting to edit the styles of all the parent elements of an element within my shadowroot using a function call, but I keep getting `Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'`. Here is my code:

```
    var child = this.shadowRoot!.host;
    var parents = [];
    while(child) {
      child = child.parentElement as HTMLElement;
      parents.unshift(child);
    }
    parents.forEach(element => {
      element.style.height='100vh';
      element.style.width='100vw';  
    })
```

I attempted to define the parents array as HTMLElements specifically, but keep getting the error `Conversion of type 'never[]' to type 'HTMLElement' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.`

How can I either define the parents array as an empty array of HTMLElements specifically, or access the 'style' property of my elements otherwise?

Comment: Cast `child` as `HTMLElement` also: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqAWYAuBTAbigTtFAPVAdgCYwASAKgLIAyAoiCgLYoFLQDeAUND9MAPYEISTAFdgSfpgAUASg7deSiKIAOWOQG5FPNGGzB4ASxBFoAXmhJjEAHQRERfgHcASv35IAhLfj9h0JDQFDT0TCxI2kp62Kr6ERAAXMFUdAzMrADaALoW0DlRvM7GDNKGJkTyXEo85aZ5dUS2cZgRYRlsQSFp4ayFSi0JtqJCxgBmSGUllf3QAL460IOsdmNStGCG0ijpERYAfAo1OLus9kgAngy+KEYA5vBI5gDkAIwADO9o8M+zPDu9JDnK4oWzOIxEawvD5fZy-HiLOayWYLOZAA)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sadly this doesn't seem to work. I'm still getting ```TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'element.style')```

Comment: That's a different error, likely one of the parent elements (say, `window`) does not have a `style` property. Check that before you add it to the array.